# How can I force one function through a set of conditionals in a separate function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, asynchronous, puppeteer

I'm working with puppeteer, and have written an async fn that takes screenshots of different pages. I loop through an array of `widgets`, append a code to the url, snap that page, and then move on. However, there are some exceptions I need to look out for on each page. e.g. `if widget === "schedule-preview"`, I need to set the viewport to be a certain size. In some cases, I also need to click elements on the dom to expand various components. I can do that inline and it works just fine:

```
// set the url
await page.goto(buildUrl(widget, config, themeColor));

// check for various conditions
if (widget === "schedule-preview") {
  if (config.label === "Default") {
    page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 2160 });
    await page.waitForSelector(`[data-list-item-key="AAA"]`);
  } else if (config.label === "Complete") {
    page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 2160 });
    await page.waitForSelector(`[data-list-item-key="BBB"]`);
  } else {
    await page.waitForSelector(
      `[aria-label="*Expand⁩"]`
    );
    await page.click(`[aria-label="*Expand"]`);
    await page.waitForSelector(
      `[data-list-item-key="00000000"]`
    );
  }
}

// snap a screenshot
await page.screenshot({
  path: `${dir}/${themeColor}.jpeg`,
  fullPage: true,
});
```

However, I wanted to extract that logic into a separate fn to make the code a bit cleaner. I created a `checkExceptions` function, passed in the necessary data, and copied all of that conditional logic into it. But the main fn just continues as if the `checkExceptions` fn isn't even there.

How can I force my fn to go through those if checks, while also separating out concerns?

EDIT: The `checkExceptions` fn was literally just those conditionals you see there, wrapped in an `async function` block.

So, essentially:

```
async function checkExceptions(widget, config, page) {
// those exact conditionals from the example above
}
```

When I called `checkExceptions` in the main fn, I tried calling it normally (so just `checkExceptions(widget, config, page)`) and with an `await`.

Didn't explicitly return anything; tried returning individual `await` statements from inside the conditional blocks, but I'm not sure why I thought that would work because in some cases I need to return a click event and two `waitForSelector`s

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `checkExceptions` function? Do you call it with await like this `await checkExceptions(..)`? Does it return promise?

Comment: Have you tried adding `concole.log`s to each of the if statements to see what's being called?

Comment: Went through it with a friend and got to the bottom of it. I was using `async/await` pretty recklessly and had missed it in key places.
Thanks for your assistance, though!

Comment: Specifically, `page.setViewport` is missing `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment thread: `async/await` was missing in some key places.